# Purpose of attaching Amazon Cognito Identity to a thing (IOTCore)

Tags: aws-iot

Can anyone share the use cases that require congnito identity attached to a thing? For user (client) to communicate with device (thing) all you need to do is attach policy to congnito identity and policy attached to thing certificate. I'd like to understand what is the purpose to attach the identity to a thing. Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

`AWS Cognito Identity Pools` allow you to give the `Thing` access to other `AWS services` such as a `DynamoDB table, S3 bucket, AWS Lambda` etc.

Using `Identity Pools` you assign `IAM roles` to `users/things` who are authenticated through a separate `Identity Provider`. Because these `users/things` are assigned an `IAM role`, they each have their own set of `IAM permissions`, allowing them to access AWS resources directly

They exist to give the appropriate credentials to the `Thing` by attaching specific `Policies` that enable the `Thing` to use the aforementioned services.

Without them the `Thing` would not have access to the rest of `AWS` which acts as a security measure, you wouldn't want a thing to be able to `read` and `write` any data in any format from `any DynamoDB table` in your account would you?

In simple terms `Identity Pools` deal with `Authorization` and the `Things` are like `users` of an application where you want to ensure they only have certain access to features of the application as they are `users`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but i believe what you mentioned can still be archived even without attaching user identity pool to thing. What im saying is as long as you attach cognito identity to policy and another policy attached to thing that should do. So what is attaching cognito identity to a thing for?

Comment: Amazon Cognito Identity is used to create temporary, limited-priviledge AWS credentials. How is a thing supposed to have access to `IoT Core` for example without the required policies?

Comment: AWS IoT Thing does not need Cognito Identity to access other services in AWS account. IoT policies regulate that access. Cognito Identity and IoT Core are separate things, but Cognito Identity can be used for example in mobile/web apps to connect and authorize with IoT Core. There is API call 'AttachThingPrincipal' which allows to attach Cognito Identity to a Thing, and I think this is what OP asked about. It is not clear from documentation what can be achieved by using this API action.

Answer (score -1):

It facilitates fine-grained access control for individual user.

Because individual user can have separate policy attached to them based on requirement.

[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/cognito-identities.html)